# Primitive values of WMI classes

Tags: .net, powershell, vbscript, wmi, jscript

This is a complicated idea, and I hope you'll bear with me as its articulation is difficult.

It seems that some WMI classes have a primitive value that can be queried, while others do not.  This has practical significance.

#### Demo 1

Take, for instance, the [Win32_Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#examples) class.  Its primitive value, as far as I can tell, is the value of its instance's `DeviceID` column.  This allows querying, for example, the architecture (32 / 64-bitness) of the running OS with a tidy one-liner, like this JScript example:

```
var arch = GetObject("winmgmts:root\\cimv2:Win32_Processor='cpu0'").AddressWidth
```

In that example, `GetObject` acts as a sort of `select instance where primitive value="cpu0"` and returns a single instance, rather than a collection.  This works as intended.

#### Demo 2

On the other hand, the [Win32_OperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class has no primitive value that I've been able to find.  Like the `Win32_Processor` class `DeviceID` column, the MSDN documentation for `Win32_OperatingSystem` claims that the `CreationClassName` column is the table's `key` field.

Assume that predictably, `CreationClassName=="Win32_OperatingSystem"`.  Therefore, one might infer that a similar one-liner could be written thusly:

```
var arch = GetObject("winmgmts:root\\cimv2:Win32_OperatingSystem='Win32_OperatingSystem'").OSArchitecture
```

**However, that results in an error.**  My trial-and-error attempts at using other column values have equally all met with failure.  Appending `.columname` between the classname and `=` results in a syntax error as well.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to identify a single instance of the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class without enumerating all instances, even if there is only one instance to enumerate.

```
var wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:");
var os = wmi.ExecQuery("select OSArchitecture from Win32_OperatingSystem");
for (var res = new Enumerator(os); !res.atEnd(); res.moveNext()) {
    var arch = res.item().OSArchitecture;
}
```

These lines can be combined somewhat:

```
var os = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("select OSArchitecture from Win32_OperatingSystem");
var arch = new Enumerator(os).item().OSArchitecture;
```

... but it'd still be nice to query an instance directly within `Win32_OperatingSystem` without having to enumerate an irritatingly vestigial hierarchy.

#### The question

How can I predict whether a WMI class has a primitive value that can be queried, and which column contains that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the 'Key' property.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/04/15/wmi-object-identifiers-and-keys.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  I used that blog author's `Get-WmiKey` function to check `Win32_OperatingSystem`.  That class apparently has no key, despite the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) regarding the `CreationClassName` property.

Answer (score 1):

In `powershell`, the [Get-WmiObject](http://ss64.com/ps/get-wmiobject.html) cmdlet (or `gwmi` alias) provides some insight that isn't obvious or readily available in MSDN.  When querying classes via `gwmi` there are some differences among classes that are either not well or not at all documented elsewhere (or at least not easily searchable).  Take the following `powershell` session for example:

[image]

You see the `Win32_Processor` class has `__RELPATH` and `__PATH` properties which refer to the class's primitive value of `CPU0`; whereas the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class has no such properties.

That could be a strong hint to help determine whether the class you wish to query must be fully enumerated before it can be parsed.